# how to call files.py from outside in python

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a login.py file and a demo.py file, both of which use pyqt5. How can I call the demo.py file to the chart function in the login.py file?

```
@pyqtSlot()
def chart(self):

    print('connect')
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Import the `demo` module into the `login` module.